# Titan/DynamoDb doesn't release all acquired locks on commit (via gremlin)

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Ok, I realise this sounds unlikely and I'm prepared to be shot down on this one but here goes...

I have a gremlin server running against titanDB and dynamoDB (local). I'm running some unit tests that keep failing due to

```
tx 0x705eafda280e already locked key-column (  8-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-128, 80-160) when tx 0x70629e1d56bf tried to lock
```

I'm running the following commands in the gremlin client console against a clean, completely empty DB (recreated between test runs using docker images). The aim of this work is to support database upgrade scripts. The original actual steps where more complete than the below but this is the minimum to reproduce the issue.

```
(Connect to local 'remote')
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml

(Add a unique constraint on a 'databaseMetadata' label which has a single 'version' property)
:> mgmt = graph.openManagement();if (!mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion")) {graph.tx().rollback();int size = graph.getOpenTransactions().size();for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { try { graph.getOpenTransactions().getAt(0).rollback();} catch(Throwable ex) { }; }; mgmt = graph.openManagement();propertyKey = (!mgmt.containsPropertyKey("version")) ? mgmt.makePropertyKey("version").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make():mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");labelObj = (!mgmt.containsVertexLabel("databaseMetadata")) ? mgmt.makeVertexLabel("databaseMetadata").make():mgmt.getVertexLabel("databaseMetadata");index = mgmt.buildIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).unique().indexOnly(labelObj).buildCompositeIndex();mgmt.setConsistency(propertyKey, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);mgmt.setConsistency(index, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);mgmt.commit();mgmt = graph.openManagement();index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion");propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) == SchemaStatus.INSTALLED) {mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();}; mgmt.commit();mgmt = graph.openManagement();index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion");propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) != SchemaStatus.ENABLED) {mgmt.commit();mgmt = graph.openManagement();mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();mgmt.commit();mgmt = graph.openManagement();mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();}; mgmt.commit();} else {index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion");propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) != SchemaStatus.ENABLED) {mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();}; mgmt.commit();};

(Add the metadata vertex with initial version '0.0.1')
:> graph.addVertex(label, "databaseMetadata").property("version", "0.0.1");graph.tx().commit();

(Update the metadata vertex with the next version - 0.0.2)
:> g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.1").property("version", "0.0.2").next();g.tx().commit();

(THIS FAILS - Update the metadata vertex with the next version - 0.0.3)
:> g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.2").property("version", "0.0.3").next();g.tx().commit();
tx 0x705eafda280e already locked key-column (  8-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-128, 80-160) when tx 0x70629e1d56bf tried to lock
```

Previously I had looked through the titan-dynamodb source and I saw that the commits/rollbacks etc of the transactions are logged, so I had changed the log level to get further information (full log file available).

When the 0.0.1 -> 0.0.2 update was executed the following locks were acquired:

```
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120479 [gremlin-server-exec-3] TRACE com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore  - acquiring lock on (  8-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-  0-128, 80-160) at 123552624951495
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120489 [gremlin-server-exec-3] TRACE com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore  - acquiring lock on (  6-137-160- 48- 46- 48- 46-177,  0) at 123552635424334
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120489 [gremlin-server-exec-3] TRACE com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore  - acquiring lock on (  6-137-160- 48- 46- 48- 46-178,  0) at 123552635704705
```

When that transaction was commited only TWO locks where released.

```
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120722 [gremlin-server-exec-3] DEBUG com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreTransaction  - commit id:0x705eafda280e
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120722 [gremlin-server-exec-3] TRACE com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore  - Expiring (  6-137-160- 48- 46- 48- 46-177,  0) in tx 0x705eafda280e because of EXPLICIT
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120722 [gremlin-server-exec-3] TRACE com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.AbstractDynamoDBStore  - Expiring (  6-137-160- 48- 46- 48- 46-178,  0) in tx 0x705eafda280e because of EXPLICIT
[33mtitan_server_1  |[0m 120722 [gremlin-server-exec-3] DEBUG org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor  - Preparing to iterate results from - RequestMessage{, requestId=09f27811-dcc3-4e53-a749-22828d34997f, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.1").property("version", "0.0.2").next();g.tx().commit();, batchSize=64}} - in thread [gremlin-server-exec-3]
```

The remaining lock ends up expiring after a few minutes, but in the mean time every other update fails as reported.

So, why does that lock not get removed? I suspect it's related to the unique index that's created, so I've either setup the index wrong (a good possibility) or this is a bug.

For ease of consumption, the (slightly shortened) index setup is below:

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
propertyKey = (!mgmt.containsPropertyKey("version")) ? mgmt.makePropertyKey("version").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make():mgmt.getPropertyKey("version")
labelObj = (!mgmt.containsVertexLabel("databaseMetadata")) ? mgmt.makeVertexLabel("databaseMetadata").make():mgmt.getVertexLabel("databaseMetadata")
index = mgmt.buildIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).unique().indexOnly(labelObj).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.setConsistency(propertyKey, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK)
mgmt.setConsistency(index, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK)
mgmt.commit()
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion")
propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version")
if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) == SchemaStatus.INSTALLED) {
  mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call()
}
mgmt.commit()
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion")
propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version")
if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) != SchemaStatus.ENABLED) {
  mgmt.commit()
  mgmt = graph.openManagement()
  mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get()
  mgmt.commit()
  mgmt = graph.openManagement()
  mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call()
}
mgmt.commit()
```

I know this is a LONG issue description, but any help would be gratefully received!

(I should also say that I tried this against the local and cloud based dynamoDb instances and had the same issue on both, so came back to the local and turned on the logging.)

I'm using titan 1.0.0 and tinkerpop 3 as set in  [dynamo-titan on github](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend).

Comment: You could additionally log a 'step number' after each statement of your index setup code to see which statement acquires and which statement releases which lock. That might lead you to the one locking statement which has no corresponding releasing statement. Then post it here.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not sure I understand you. The indexes are created... then time passes... it's only when the '0.0.1 -> 0.0.2' upgrade is run that the troublesome lock is acquired. Can you give an example of logging the 'step number' in the context of the above? I would understand this problem happening if I'm not got the right number of commits/rollbacks but AFAICT I've got them covered.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the index creation steps are correct?

Comment: I see. You're sure that these log entries are definitely produced by the last two statements of your code? Is it all single-threaded? Btw, you can also store metadata [directly on the graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_graph_variables), but I don't know if that would support indexing. Example step num: `statement1; log.info(i++); statement2; log.info(i++)...` just to know when the locking/releasing occurs

Comment: Your indexing looks very good. Could you try this? `g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.2").property("version", "0.0.3").iterate();` for both 0.0.1 to 0.0.2 and 0.0.2 to 0.0.3, with a `commit()` after each.

Comment: I'm pretty confident regarding the statements. Definitely single threaded as I restarted, cleaned out the DB (docker contained) and ran the commands manually in the gremlin console. Nothing else was running against the (local) DB at the time... ....will try your suggestion....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135405/discussion-between-john-stephenson-and-double-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got repro and and found your issue. Basically, the LRU cache pulls its expiry time from storage.lock.expiry-time config. Default is 5 minutes, so if you try to make changes before 5 minutes pass, yes, the AbstractDynamoDBStore.keyColumnLocalLocks LRU cache will not let you make the second change. By reducing expiry-time and Thread.sleep() before making the second change, you allow the second change to claim the lock again and succeed.

```
//default lock expiry time is 300*1000 ms = 5 minutes. Set to 100ms.
config.setProperty("storage.lock.expiry-time", 100);
```

Comment: If you agree with my [repro here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/master/src/test/java/com/amazon/janusgraph/ScenarioTests.java#L79), please accept this answer as well :)

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/master/src/test/java/com/amazon/janusgraph/ScenarioTests.java#L84

Comment: I've accepted this, as after setting it in my properties file (as opposed to code) with: `storage.lock.expiry-time=100`. Although, I have a follow on question of why a timeout would fix this, as I'd expect the column locks to be released with the commit/rollbacks, else it seems likely that this probably could occur intermittently again.

Comment: I created an issue on the project to track the question of [releasing locks on commit()/rollback()](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/issues/215)

Comment: I believe I have nailed the issue of locks not being released in the same JVM in [my recent fix](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend/pull/231).

Answer (score 2):

F.y.i. I have run all of your above code in Java using a Berkeley storage backend.

```
TitanGraph graph = ...;
TitanManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey propertyKey = (!mgmt.containsPropertyKey("version"))
        ? mgmt.makePropertyKey("version").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
        : mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");
VertexLabel labelObj = (!mgmt.containsVertexLabel("databaseMetadata"))
        ? mgmt.makeVertexLabel("databaseMetadata").make() 
        : mgmt.getVertexLabel("databaseMetadata");
TitanGraphIndex index = mgmt.buildIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).unique()
        .indexOnly(labelObj).buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(propertyKey, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
mgmt.setConsistency(index, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
mgmt.commit();
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion");
propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");
if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) == SchemaStatus.INSTALLED) {
    try {
        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph,"bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
mgmt.commit();
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion");
propertyKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey("version");
if (index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey) != SchemaStatus.ENABLED) {
    mgmt.commit();
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    try {
        mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("bydatabaseMetadataversion"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mgmt.commit();
    mgmt = graph.openManagement();
    try {
        ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "bydatabaseMetadataversion").status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED)
                        .timeout(10, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES).call();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
mgmt.commit();
```

Then the operations on the graph;

```
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();

graph.addVertex("databaseMetadata").property("version", "0.0.1");
graph.tx().commit();

g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.1").property("version", "0.0.2").iterate();
g.tx().commit();

g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.1").property("version", "0.0.2").iterate();
g.tx().commit();

g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version", "0.0.2").property("version", "0.0.3").iterate();
g.tx().commit();

g.V().hasLabel("databaseMetadata").has("version").properties("version").forEachRemaining(prop -> {
    System.out.println("Version: " + prop.value());
});
```

The result was:

```
Version: 0.0.3
```

Sadly, the `iterate()` alteration of your query only applies to Java. Your scripts should work as they are. Because of the result of my experiment I strongly suspect that the DynamoDB backend is causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts - I'll ping the dynamoDB guys and report back...

Comment: FYI - this is the [issue on github](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/58)

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I'll keep an eye on it. Would be nice if you also posted the result here once it's hopefully resolved.

Comment: will definitely do that :-)

Comment: FYI it sounds [from here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/60) that Titan will left for [Janus Graph](http://janusgraph.org/) (a fork). I'm not sure what that means for anything but it would be good if Amazon would tell the people reading their shiny titan/dynamoDb pages!?!